Why is $y(n)=Ax(n)+B$ not relaxed if $B\neq 0$?
I'm wondering why $y(n)=Ax(n)+B$ not relaxed if $B\neq 0$?
The definition of a relaxed system as I've understood is that $y(n)$ does not depend on any $y$-values. So what is the definition of a relaxed system and how can I check it for $y(n)$?

For starters it would not be an LTI system anymore

ah c'mon @PeterK. ... before it was better.  more indecipherable.

By definition, a linear system is said to be relaxed at time $t_0$ if and only if $y(t) = 0,\forall t\leq t_0$ (no stored energy in the system). With this definition, the affine dynamic system $y(t) = Ax(t)+b, b\neq 0$ is not a relaxed system.

Can u explain why $y(n)=e^{x(n)}$ is relaxed?

The sustem is causal and there is no stored energy in the system. The output is zero when there is no input.
